# Assignment operator crash in xcode 4, runs fine in MSVS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, xcode4, exc-bad-access

I was working on a C++ project with visual studio 2010 and everything was fine but when i tried to run my program with xcode 4 it raises Bas_Access exception. I think it's because of a memory leak but I'm not sure about how to solve the problem. 
I have the following function:

```
// Search is my class with x and y as members and here's is a constructor
// that I cretae in my Search.cpp class
Search& Search::operator=( const Search& search )
{
    if(this != &search)
   {
      x = search.x;
      y = search.y;
   }
   return *this;
}
```

And here is how my function is called:

```
Search searchStart(0,0);
//I created my tempSearch and initialized it with the start Search element
Search tempSearch(searchStart);
//bestSolution is a function that calculates the best neighbour node around the searchStart node, it returns a Search element. And stores it in a list in storage.
Search * tempCurrent=searchStart.bestSolution(&storage);
//Here I call my function
tempSearch=*tempCurrent;
```

I'm simply creating a new Search element from an existing element but it gives me exception at

```
x=search.x;
```

It works perfectly with visual studio.

EDIT:
I just added the code where my function is called. Excuse me for not being able to provide the full code because it's really long.

EDIT:
Here's my bestSolution function:

```
Search * searchNode::Search::bestSolution(Storage *storage )
{
        //listResult is a type defined as std::list<Search *> listResult.
    listResult::iterator it, it1;
    listResult tempList;
    //I've initialized the result element at (0,0) because it was creating problems
    // if uninitialized
        Search *result=new Search(0,0);
    //openList is a simple list of Search elements
    if(!storage->openList.empty()){
    for(it=storage->openList.begin();it!=storage->openList.end();it++)
    {
        tempList.push_back((*it));
    }
    tempList.reverse();
    it1=tempList.begin();
    // getDistanceCost is a function that calculates the heuristic distance 
    // between two points and works fine
    int fCost=(*it1)->getDistanceCost();    
    for(it1=storage->openList.begin();it1!=storage->openList.end();it1++)
    {
        if((*it1)->getDistanceCost()<=fCost){
        fCost=(*it1)->getDistanceCost();
        result=(*it1);
    }
    }

    }

    return result;
    }
```

Comment: Is it a compile or runtime error?

Comment: how is the `operator=` invoked? by any chance you are trying to use an already deallocated memory?

Comment: Is it really `x=Search.x` or is it `x=search.x`? It's a huge difference.

Comment: what is the error? also, why don't you implement this as a copy constructor?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore it's a runtime error I guess coz when I simply build the project there's is no problem.

Comment: Then, why don't you just add the exact error you get to your post?

Comment: @DvirVolk arriving at this instruction the program stops and raises a EXC_BAD_ACCESS, i don't have any other information about the error which makes it a bit hard to locate it.

Comment: @bitmask as i just explained I'm not getting any explicit errors except this exception, and yes it's search.x.

Comment: Yes, saw that now. Still you should provide the code where your `Search::operator=` is invoked.

Comment: You should probably provide the code to the `bestSolution` method as well.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `bestSolution` is returning a pointer to an object allocated on stack. Now when you try to `tempSearch=*tempCurrent` you are trying to copy values into this invalid pointer which causes the undefined behavior.

**EDIT**

Looking at the implementation of the `bestSolution` method, I assume `listResult` contains `Search*` as its nodes as you are doing `result=(*it1);`. It looks like the `Search` object to which the list has a pointer was *deleted after* it was inserted into the list. So what you have in the list is an invaid pointer. If you try to copy anything to the memory pointed by this invalid pointer, your program will behave unpredictably.

Answer (score 0):

Given the information you provided it is certain that the problem lies in

```
Search * tempCurrent=searchStart.bestSolution(&storage);
```

It must return some invalid pointer (perhaps `NULL`).

This invalid pointer is then passed as the `search` parameter (more precisely as `&search`) to your `Search::operator=` which then tries to access the `x` (and later the `y`) member of this invalid pointer (`search.x` and `search.y`).

Comment: ok but when i compile in visual studio and it works for me there was no problem because at the beginning i was blocked because of these pointers but now that it worked I thought it'll work anywhere. Is there a difference between when you compile with xcode or with VS?

Comment: @Anila: Most probably you are relying some sort of undefined behavior. Can you show us the code (or atleast the memory allocation part) of `bestSolution` method?

Comment: @Anila: Could be, especially if you rely on undefined behavior...which is my guess that you do.

Comment: @Asha i've added my bestSolution function to the post

Comment: @Anila: Which raises the question where and how you populate your `storage->openList`.

Comment: :) I simply add all the Search* nodes in openList with openList.push_back;

Comment: @Anila: The problem could be there, that's why I mentioned it.

Comment: ahan, ok I'll try to dig a little deeper the functions where i populate my lists. Thanks.